# Return user roles from bearer token of Web API

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token

I am developing a Web API 2 project. For authentication I am using bearer token. On successful authentication the API returns a JSON object.

```
{"access_token":"Vn2kwVz...",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "expires_in":1209599,
   "userName":"username",
   ".issued":"Sat, 07 Jun 2014 10:43:05 GMT",
   ".expires":"Sat, 21 Jun 2014 10:43:05 GMT"}
```

Now I want to return the user roles as well in this JSON object. What changes do I need to make in order to get the user roles from JSON response?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

After searching a lot i found that i can create some custom properties and can set them with the authentication ticket. In this way you can customize the response so that it can have the custom values which may be required at the caller end.

Here is the code to send the user roles along with the token. which was my requirement. one can modify the code to send the required data.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        using (UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = _userManagerFactory())
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                context.Options.AuthenticationType);

            ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            List<Claim> roles = oAuthIdentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).ToList();
            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(roles.Select(x=>x.Value)));

            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        }
    }


 public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName, string Roles)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "userName", userName },
            {"roles",Roles}
        };
        return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }
```

This will return me the out put as

```
`{"access_token":"Vn2kwVz...",
 "token_type":"bearer",
 "expires_in":1209599,
 "userName":"username",
 ".issued":"Sat, 07 Jun 2014 10:43:05 GMT",
 ".expires":"Sat, 21 Jun 2014 10:43:05 GMT"
 "roles"=["Role1","Role2"] }`
```

Hope this information will be helpful to some one. :)

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work for me yet. I try creating the `AuthenticationProperties` object with the extra parameters, but it still returns only the access_token, the token_type and the expires_in values. Did you have to configure anything else for this to work?

Comment: The .issued and .expires values are not set down either in my case.

Comment: @MarkVincze You have to override TokenEndpoint as well, as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24389232/224087

Comment: @Sachin, value for roles is another string (not json array) i.e. "roles":"[\"Role1\",\"Role2\"]", is there any way i could return an extended response property as json object?

Comment: @Haider You can parse this roles string as per your need wherever you are consuming it. Or may be you can serialize the Roles object when you are adding it to directory. {"roles",Roles}. I am not sure of that but that will definitely help you to return json object.

Comment: I don't know why this is not the default. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I have similar problem as Haider. I need json collection but i receive string.If i pass List<Roles> i receive error that jsonSerializer cannot serialize complex objects such Lists. Is there any way to customize overall object that return to client after successful Authentication?

Comment: @qes I then used `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in context.Properties.Dictionary) context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(pair.Key, pair.Value));` in the overridden `TokenEndpoint` method to add the properties that were set in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` per Sachin's answer.

Comment: Thank you, you have no idea how much time I spent on this!

Comment: If you need an array of items instead of string, just override the response stream https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841971/asp-net-oauth-authorization-server-add-an-array-as-additional-response-paramete

Answer (score 5):

Above changes are good to return roles as expected with one additional method in AuthorizationProvider as below: (Add this method and rock with roles...)

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
            {
                context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
```