# Customize Bearer token JSON result in ASP.NET WebApi 2

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, access-token, asp.net-identity

I walkthrough [this official ASP.NET tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api), and the bearer token is published as below JSON.

```
{
    "access_token":"boQtj0SCGz2GFGz[...]",
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "expires_in":1209599,
    "userName":"Alice",
    ".issued":"Mon, 14 Oct 2013 06:53:32 GMT",
    ".expires":"Mon, 28 Oct 2013 06:53:32 GMT"
}
```

I'd like to add user profile properties along with the above result in order to reduce number of requests from clients. The example is as below...

```
{
    "access_token":"boQtj0SCGz2GFGz[...]",
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "expires_in":1209599,
    "userName":"Alice",
    ".issued":"Mon, 14 Oct 2013 06:53:32 GMT",
    ".expires":"Mon, 28 Oct 2013 06:53:32 GMT",
    "Notifications":35,
    "IsEventMember":true,
    "Promotion":324372
}
```

The oauth provider I use is from default ASP.NET template (`ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs`) and `OAuthOption` is as below.

```
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

How can I make it?

Note that my question is different from [adding extra claims](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21675844/361100).

Comment: I found that my question is duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24078905/361100

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well here is the solution:

```
public override async Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("username", "user@mail.com");

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```